# Why i can't remove other array element in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, array-splice

I am working with arrays now but if I remove the second element that I choose the first one that I removed keeps returning to its spot. How can I solve this?

**Here is the Code:**

```
const fruits = ['Apple', 'Banana','Lemon', 'Guava'];

const removeItem = (arr, item) => {
    let newArray = [...arr];
    const index = newArray.findIndex((element)=>element===item)
    if(index !== -1){
        newArray.splice(index, 1)
        return newArray
    }
}

console.log(removeItem(fruits, 'Guava'))

console.log(removeItem(fruits, 'Lemon'))
```

**Output:**

```
(3) ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Lemon'] //I removed Guava
(3) ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Guava'] //I removed Lemon
```

Comment: thank you so much, I forgot that I've used the const

Answer (score 0):

Your original array is a `const` and cannot be updated. So it is using all original values. Here is a working version that removes from the original array.

```js
let fruits = ['Apple', 'Banana','Lemon', 'Guava'];

const removeItem = (arr, item) => {
    let newArray = [...arr];
    const index = newArray.findIndex((element)=>element===item)
    if(index !== -1){
        newArray.splice(index, 1)
        fruits = newArray;
        return newArray
    }
    
}

console.log(removeItem(fruits, 'Guava'))

console.log(removeItem(fruits, 'Lemon'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Keywords to think about: pop push remove index placeholder
I don't understand what you are trying to achieve.
Well, I never tried Guava.